# Как сделать вызов асинхронным rxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, rxjava, rxandroid

У меня сейчас стоит задача получить список данных из интернета, через retrofit. И если код ответа не успешный(200), то взять этот список данных из бд(room).
Как мне сделать это правильно с rxJava?
Я использую паттерн mvvm, и проверку я делаю в методе модели, этот метод потом вызывает viewmodel.

Сначала я думал делать поток в viewmodel и мне показалось это хорошим решением,но после появления дб, я понял что в модели должны обрабатываться запросы(асинхронно скорее всего) и возвращать мне нужный список моделей.

Сейчас код модели выглядит так:

```
fun getPeviewCards(): Observable<List<BasePokeModel>> {
        var pokeList: List<BasePokeModel> = listOf()
        apiService.getAllCards()
//            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
//            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map {
                pokesList = BasePokeModel.cast(it.body()!!.poke) { pokeInfo ->
                    BasePokeModel(poke.name, poke.images.small)
                }
            }
            .onErrorReturn {
                pokeDao.getAll().map {
                    pokesList = BasePokeModel.cast(it) { pokeInfo ->
                        BasePokeModel(pokeInfo.name, pokeInfo.images.small)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Понятное дело этот код не работает как надо, он возвращает пустой лист, т.к это многопоток а не асинхронность.
В итоге как я понимаю мне нужна асинхронность, как её добиться с rx?
Retrofit и Room возвращают Single<>

Переделанное в цепочку

```
 model.getPreviewRetrofitPokes()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe({ onNext ->
                model.refreshTable(onNext.pokes)
                if (onNext.pokes.size != pokesLiveData.value?.size) {
                    val pokesList = BasePokeModel.cast(onNext.pokes) { pokeInfo ->
                        BasePokeModel(pokeInfo.name, pokeInfo.images.small)
                    }
                    pokesLiveData.postValue(pokesList)
                }
            }, {
                model.getPreviewRoomCards()
                    .subscribe({ dbPokes ->
                        var pokeList = listOf<BasePokeModel>()
                        if (dbPokes.isNotEmpty())
                            pokeList = BasePokeModel.cast(dbPoke) { pokeInfo ->
                                BasePokeModel(pokeInfo.name, pokeInfo.images.small)
                            }
                        pokeLiveData.postValue(pokeList)
                    },
                        {
                            Log.d("ErrorDb", it.stackTraceToString())
                        })
            }
            )
```

Comment: У вас что-то странное написано. По идее вам не нужна переменная pokeList. Зачем она вам?

Comment: Она должна быть возвращена, ниже написан был return pokeList. Но потом я понял, что оно выполняется в другом потоке и не ожидается и return возвращает пустой список.

Comment: Всё верно, оно так и сработало бы, если бы вы запустили rx-цепочку. Одновременно (примерно) с возвращением пустого списка данных пошёл бы запрос в сеть, потом, опционально, запрос в БД и результат бы проигнорировался бы. Вам надо  вовращать именно саму rx цепочку и подписываться на неё в презентере/вьюмодели методом subscribe. В subscribe же надо передать лямбды для приёма данных/ошибки. И вот в первой лямбде у вас и будут ваши данные из сети/из БД

Comment: Я вроде как пределал, считается ли это цепочкой? Правда return не получилось сделать в моделях, поэтому я вынес их по разные методы, поток запустил в вьюмодели, и когда мне надо вызываю методы моделей

Comment: единственное что напрягает в том что я написал, что приходится внутри подписаного на получение ретрофитовских кард, подписываться на бд, в итоге получается не цепочка, разве не так?

Comment: Я в ответе написал как примерно должно выглядеть. Subscribe внутри Subscribe - всегда плохо, не делайте так)

Comment: Просто интересно, а зачем нужен rx если есть livedata и/или наоборот, корутин явно не хватает )

Comment: Я бы использовал корутины, но по условию нужно использовать rx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно примерно так выглядеть из presenter/viewModel

```
model.getDataFromApi()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map { /* тут конвертация модели с сервера в общую модель */ }
    .onErrorResumeNext(
         model.getDataFromDb()
           .map { /* тут конвертация модели с БД в общую модель */ }
    )
    .subscribe(
         {
             /*список общих моделек тут*/
             pokeLiveData.postValue(it)
         },
         { /*какая-то непредвиденная ошибка тут*/ }
    )
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду иметь представление как делать с цепочками

Comment: А еще будет вопрос. Если у меня по получению данных с сервера т.е в первой map нужно обновить бд(для этого есть отдельный метод), как мне внутри этого метода по обновлению бд без `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` обновлять бд или тут не обойтись уже? Т.е есть метод `refreshDb(retrofitList)` в нем `{ /*получение списка из бд, конвертация ретрофит списка в дб модель*/ dao.insertAll(convertedList)}` вот это получение списка нужно в другом потоке запустить иначе ошибка(потому что Single возвращает). Сам метод запускаю в первой map

Comment: Не вполне ясно что именно вы хотите, но, наверное, вам нужен оператор doOnSuccess после запроса в сеть и перед map. В нём можете в БД сложить то, что пришло ранее из сети.